# Excel VBA-Run-time error 438. Object doesn't support this property or method. When trying to copy website table to excel

Tags: vba, excel, internet-explorer

I am trying to extract table from an internal website to excel by giving some input parameters. Everything works until it refreshes the website data with my inputs. The part I get the run-time error 438 is marked (`For r = 1 To elemCollection.Rows.Length - 1`). I also tried to load the data from website to excel using web query and the table wasn't showing up on my excel spreadsheet. "It gives the following error-This page might not function correctly because either your browser does not support scripts or active scripting is disabled. Your browser does not support scripts or has been configured not to allow scripts. The report viewer web control http handler has not been registered in the application's web config file."

Wondering if this has anything to do with permissions.

VBA code below:

```
Option Explicit
Sub Macro1()

  Dim IE As Object, obj As Object
  Dim StartDate As Object
  Dim EndDate As Object
  Dim myState As String
  Dim r As Integer, c As Integer, t As Integer
  Dim elemCollection As Object, curHTMLRow As Object
  Dim wb As Workbook
  Dim ws As Worksheet
  Dim objCollection As Object
  Dim objElement As Object
  Dim i As Long

  Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

  IE.Visible = True

  IE.navigate ("http://internalwebsite_SSRSReport")

  ' we ensure that the web page downloads completely before we fill the form automatically
  While IE.ReadyState <> 4: DoEvents: Wend

  IE.Document.All.Item("ctl31_ctl03_txtValue").InnerText = Format("7/1/2016", "m/d/yyyy")
  IE.Document.All.Item("ctl31_ctl05_txtValue").InnerText = Format("7/31/2016", "m/d/yyyy")

  Wait 2

  IE.Document.getElementsByName("ctl31_ctl04_divDropDown").Item.Click

  Wait 2

  ' accessing the button
  IE.Document.getElementsByName("ctl31_ctl04_ctl00").Item.Click
  Wait 2
  ' again ensuring that the web page loads completely before we start scraping data
  While IE.busy: DoEvents: Wend

      Wait 2

     'Clearing any unnecessary or old data in Sheet1
      ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Activate
      Range("A1:K500").ClearContents

      Set elemCollection =  IE.Document.getelementbyId("ctl31_ctl09_ReportArea")

      'error here
      For r = 1 To elemCollection.Rows.Length - 1

      Set curHTMLRow = elemCollection.Rows(r)
      For c = 0 To curHTMLRow.Cells.Length - 1
          Cells(r + 1, c + 1) = curHTMLRow.Cells(c).InnerText
      Next
  Next

  ' cleaning up memory
  IE.Quit
  Set IE = Nothing

End Sub
Private Sub Wait(ByVal nSec As Long)
    nSec = nSec + Timer
    While nSec > Timer
        DoEvents
    Wend
End Sub
```

Comment: Are you trying to read the TD's of each TR from the website?

Comment: HI Ryan,I have a huge dataset that I would like to copy from my website. How do I make this work for large data set? Many thanks in advance!  For Each TR In TR_Elements
        Set TD_Elements = TR.getElementsByTagName("td")
        ColumnNumb = 1
        For Each TD In TD_Elements
            'Consider using an array to save the values to memory if there is going
            'to be a lot of data to be moved over
            ActiveSheet.Cells(RowNumb, ColumnNumb).Value = TD.InnerText
            ColumnNumb = ColumnNumb + 1
        Next
        RowNumb = RowNumb + 1
    Next

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is some code that should be able to grab the data from the HTML table from the SSRS report and extract it to Excel.

Basically the code will iterate through all the TRs and TDs in the Table Element, and output the InnerText to Excel. If you are moving *a lot* of data over, please consider writing to an array, then doing the write all at once by setting to an equally sized range object.

I also cleaned up the code, mostly removing variables that were not referenced and reduced some of the lines by combining some statements together

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub GetSSRSData()
    On Error GoTo errhand:
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim IE            As Object: Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    Dim TR_Elements   As Object
    Dim TR            As Object ' Table Row
    Dim TD_Elements   As Object
    Dim TD            As Object ' Table Data
    Dim RowNumb       As Integer
    Dim Columns       As Integer
    Dim ColumnNumb    As Integer

    With IE
        .Visible = True
        .Navigate ("http://internalwebsite_SSRSReport")

        While .ReadyState <> 4: DoEvents: Wend ' Wait for page load
        'Fill the form out with dates
        .Document.All.Item("ctl31_ctl03_txtValue").InnerText = Format("7/1/2016", "m/d/yyyy")
        .Document.All.Item("ctl31_ctl05_txtValue").InnerText = Format("7/31/2016", "m/d/yyyy")
        Wait 2

        'Click the DropDown
        .Document.getElementsByName("ctl31_ctl04_divDropDown").Item.Click
        Wait 2

        ' Click the other button
        .Document.getElementsByName("ctl31_ctl04_ctl00").Item.Click
    End With

    Wait 2
    While IE.busy: DoEvents: Wend ' Wait for page load
    Wait 2

    'Clearing any unnecessary or old data in Sheet1
    Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:K500").ClearContents
    Set TR_Elements = IE.Document.getelementbyId("ctl31_ctl09_ReportArea").getElementsByTagName("tr")
    RowNumb = 1
    ColumnNumb = 1
    'Tables usually consists of TR (Table Rows), and -
    'TD (Table Data)
    For Each TR In TR_Elements
        Set TD_Elements = TR.getElementsByTagName("td")
        ColumnNumb = 1
        For Each TD In TD_Elements
            'Consider using an array to save the values to memory if there is going
            'to be a lot of data to be moved over
            ActiveSheet.Cells(RowNumb, ColumnNumb).Value = TD.InnerText
            ColumnNumb = ColumnNumb + 1
        Next
        RowNumb = RowNumb + 1
    Next

    ' cleaning up memory
    IE.Quit
    Set IE = Nothing
    Set TD_Elements = Nothing
    Set TR_Elements = Nothing
    Set TD = Nothing
    Set TR = Nothing
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

errhand:
     Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

Private Sub Wait(ByVal nSec As Long)
    nSec = nSec + Timer
    While nSec > Timer
        DoEvents
    Wend
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi there, not sure I follow the question. The table should be pulled over in the same format from the web.

Comment: You're awesome Ryan! Thank you so very much!

Comment: Please ignore my earlier Q, deleted it. Thank you very much again!